# Issue while displaying fields of docs in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to programming and trying my best but without any help I don't think I am able to find it ;)
I want to display all products from mongoDB by brand. I already have route for category but in the same time when I am trying to implement the same strategy to brands I have 404 not found.
my code :

```
router.get('/:categorySlug', (req, res, next) => {

let filter = {};
if(req.query.hasOwnProperty("filter")){
    filter['price'] = req.query.price
}

const slug = req.params.categorySlug;
Category.findOne({slug: slug})
.select('_id')
.exec()
.then(category => {
    if(category){
        if(category.parent === ""){
            Product.find({category: category._id})
            .select('_id name price productPic category brand slug')
            .sort(filter)
            .exec()
            .then(products => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: products
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: error
                })
            })
        }
    }else{
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Not Found'
        })
    }
})
.catch(er => {
    res.status(500).json({
        error: er
    });
});



router.get('/:brandSlug', (req, res, next) => {

const slug = req.params.brandSlug;
Brand.findOne({slug: slug})
.select('_id parent')
.exec()
.then(brand => {
    if(brand){
            Product.find({brand: brand._id})
            .select('_id name price productPic brand slug')
            .exec()
            .then(products => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: products
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: error
                })
            })
    }else{
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Not Found'
        })
    }
})
.catch(er => {
    res.status(500).json({
        error: er
    });
});
```

Category, brand and product schema :

```
const brandSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name: { type: String, required: true },
slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },


const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name: { type: String, required: true },
slug: { type: String, unique: true },


const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name: { type: String, required: true },
slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
price: { type: Number, required: true },
oldPrice: { type: Number, default: 0 },
stock: { type: Number, required: true },
description: { type: String },
productPic: [
    {
        img: String
    }
],
keyword: {type: String},
category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true  },
brand: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Brand', required: true }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you try to get the brands in the front end?

Comment: Dont have front end. Just building an api now and while sending GET req from Postman for /products/:categorySlug is working but for brands is not and now idea why

Comment: @HubertKopyść : My answer explains what was missing in part of the code, Anyway to check why you're not getting brand (at here :: `if(brand)`), Can you try to print this `req.params.brandSlug` & execute the same `.findOne()` query directly in MongoDB & check if any doc is being returned for that input or not?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do two DB calls to get that required data, Instead you can join those two collections & get required data in one DB call ( Try to read about **MongoDB**'s native [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) or **Mongoose**'s [`.populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) - which is a kind of wrapper to `$lookup` ).

But for now you can replace this :

```
Product.find({brand: brand._id})
```

with :

```
Product.find({brand: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(brand._id)})
```

Actual issue is `brand._id` is a string in code (In general when you read docs of `brand` collection in MongoDB & then log/print it or even use it in code You can see **`ObjectId()`**'s are converted to **string**'s as `ObjectId()` is from **BSON** & not supported by **JSON**). So you need to convert input (`brand._id`) from string to `ObjectId()` before firing a query to product collection as brand field in product collection is of type **`ObjectId()`** !!

> **Note :** Do not forget to import **mongoose** in this file otherwise it would fail that given point.